# Wrapping up Asp.net Framework 4.0 in 3.5

Tags: spring.net

I am working on an application in VS 2010 and using Asp.net framework 4.0 which i just migrated from Framework 3.5. The reason i had to migrate it to 4.0 is, i have a third party toolkit dll which is built in Framework 4.0, so in order to include it i had to change target framework of this project to 4.0. As, this project is being referred from other projects ans so on.., i end up  converting whole application to framework 4.0. Every thing worked okay but as the application is using spring.net also, after successfully building the application, i found broken controls on almost all the pages. i am getting java script errors (about undefined control)for usercontrol PopupDatePickerControl we are using in the application. i downloaded and included latest version of Spring.net.  i have no idea what is causing this problem. Please help if any one has experience working with this combination of framework 4.0 and spring.net? OR there is any way out to wrap up Framework 4.0 into 3.5. so i don't have to do this Migration.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you trace with for instance Fiddler/Firebug if the javascript files your controls are requesting are not delivered. Imho this is due to a misconfiguration in your web.config (httphandler, httpmodule, axd).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a shot in the dark on so many levels.  It's probably not the combination of 4.0 and Spring.NET, unless you aren't referencing the correct Spring.NET dlls.  Can you post parts of your IoC configuration and a rough outline of your app's architecture?

Also, what is the other third party toolkit you mentioned?